# When can I set a variable substitution in a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was trying to prove the following limit to solve an olympiad problem, does someone knows of a counter example or a proof?
Suppose we have a function (not necessarily continuous) $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ s.t. $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$.
If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(f(x))= \infty$, can we say that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$ ?

I have tried an epsilon delta argument. I have the following:

$\forall \; M>0$ and $\epsilon>0 \; \exists \; N>0 $ s.t. if $x>N$ then $f(x)<\epsilon$ and  $f(f(x))>M$. If I want to have $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$, then for this M, I need a $\delta>0$ s.t. if $x<\delta$ then $f(x)>M$. But the fact that $f(x)<\epsilon=\delta $ and $f(f(x))>M$ when $x>N$  does not means that **for all** $x<\delta, \; f(x)<M$ because f may not take all the values less than $\delta$ as it should take in the limit. Then is there a counterexample?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Try epsilon delta argument

Comment: I tried but i don't see clear that I can choose any delta so that the conclusion follows.

Comment: *"Suppose we have a function (not necessarily continuous)"* <<< If the function was supposed to be continuous, then your proposition would be true. A proof would make use of the intermediate value theorem or something equivalent. If the function is not supposed continuous, then the proposition is false;  you can find a counterexample in the answer below, but you can also try to build you own (hint: lim f(f(x)) = infity only implies that lim f(y_n) = infinity for particular sequences (y_n) that can be written as a y_n = f(x_n), i.e., sequences that stay inside the image of f).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative and here is a counterexample:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}&\text{if }x\ge1\\
n&\text{if }x=\frac1n,\quad n\in\Bbb N\\
0&\text{else.}
\end{cases}$$